# Exceptions handling when using annotated POJOs for Websockets in Jetty9

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

We're trying to implement a basic websocket handling using jetty9. Everything is done according to the manual.

```
@WebServlet  
public class SocketsServer extends WebSocketHandler {

@Override
public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
    factory.getPolicy().setIdleTimeout(100000);
    factory.register(SocketClient.class);
}

@WebSocket(maxMessageSize = 64 * 1024)
public static class SocketClient {

    @OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onConnect(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Connected: " + toString());
        throw new RuntimeException("fail");
    }
}
```

}

Please note the `throw new RuntimeException("fail");` line. If a runtime exception is thrown in one of those annotated POJO's methods, it is silently ignored, and the client disconnects. This may somehow be useful for the production environment (maybe?), but it is a terrible behavior for the developer. So, the question is, how can we handle and/or log all the exceptions in these methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have pieces of information about this scenario that you are not opting to pay attention to.

1. The close code and reason
2. Any errors

Let me start by showing you what I mean in code

```java
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketClose;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketConnect;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketError;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketMessage;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.WebSocket;

@WebSocket
public class AnnotatedTextSocket
{
    @OnWebSocketClose
    public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason)
    {
        System.out.printf("onClose(%d, %s)%n",statusCode,reason);
    }

    @OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onConnect(Session sess)
    {
        System.out.printf("onConnect(%s)%n",sess);
    }

    @OnWebSocketError
    public void onError(Throwable cause)
    {
        System.out.printf("onError(%s: %s)%n",cause.getClass().getSimpleName(),cause.getMessage());
        cause.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onText(String message)
    {
        System.out.printf("onText(%s)%n",message);
    }
}
```

You will note the `@OnWebSocketClose` will show you that the local socket was closed due to an abnormal condition.

And the `@OnWebSocketError` will pass you the various exceptions that led up to the closure.

Note: this notification behavior is also consistent with how the future JSR-356, The Java WebSocket API (aka javax.websocket) will work in your scenario.

Comment: I thought this could be the purpose of `@OnWebSocketError` method. I've tried the code you provided, but the server console doesn't show any indications of methods other than `onConnect` being invoked.

Comment: Odd, that's what it should do. I went ahead and opened a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/410537